# laravel Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json

Tags: laravel, composer-php

hi In Laravel Installation
The following error occurred

```
user@user-System-Product-Name:/$ composer global require "laravel/installer"
Changed current directory to /home/user/.config/composer

Using version ^2.0 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v2.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v2.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.0.0, v2.0.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
I'm using the latest composer version...
php7 , mysql , apache2  already installed

Comment: You have install php-zip extension

Comment: php zip already installed . 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/zip.soy' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/zip.soy: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: That message clearly stats that the ZIP library was not found. Why is the file extension `.soy`? Looks like a typo in your php.ini

Answer (score 5):

Just need zip extension:

```
# For php v7.2
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```

Answer (score 4):

it says `the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.`

you have to enable or install that.

```
# For php v7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip

# For php v7.1
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```

Comment: its say php7.1-zip is already the newest version (7.1.11-0ubuntu0.17.10.1).

Comment: please run this command: `composer install -v`  so you can find which extensions you are missing.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/zip.soy' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/zip.soy: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

I worked by previously installing Composer, after php.

Run:
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip

sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me was updating my PHP to 7.4 with Brew.

```
brew install php@7.4
```

Nothing else worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you use php 7.3

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
```

or simply if you are not sure with the version, just use code below

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me was install php-xml

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Comment: Do you mean that the other options suggested in the other answers did not work for you?